# How to get data from DataSource.Factory

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack

I have to call this method to get all the persons. I cannot modify this method at all.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM PERSON_TABLE ORDER BY NAME DESC"
abstract fun getElements(): DataSource.Factory<Int, Person>
```

Then in an `Activity` I am calling it like this:

```
override fun onCreate(...)
{
    ...

    val data = dao.getElements()
}
```

I want to get all the `Person`s, possibly as a list. How do I do this?

I don't understand how `DataSource.Factory<Int, Person>` works.

Comment: What is `DataSource.Factory<Int, Person>`? is it the class from some library?

Comment: It is not a library, it is another area in the code. But `DataSource.Factory` is from Android https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/DataSource.Factory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/ui):

> Typically, your UI code observes a LiveData object (or, if you're using RxJava2, a Flowable or Observable object), which resides in your app's ViewModel. This observable object forms a connection between the presentation and contents of your app's list data.
>
> In order to create one of these observable PagedList objects, pass in
>   an instance of DataSource.Factory to a LivePagedListBuilder or
>   RxPagedListBuilder object. A DataSource object loads pages for a
>   single PagedList. The factory class creates new instances of PagedList
>   in response to content updates, such as database table invalidations
>   and network refreshes. The Room persistence library can provide
>   DataSource.Factory objects for you, or you can build your own.

The sample code is as following:

```
// The Int type argument corresponds to a PositionalDataSource object.
val data: DataSource.Factory<Int, Person> = dao.getElements()

val dataList: LiveData<PagedList<Person>> = LivePagedListBuilder(data, /* page size */ 20).build()
```

So you need to pass your `DataSource.Factory<Int, Person>` object to `LivePagedListBuilder` and at the end you will get `LiveData<PagedList<Person>>` which you can observe.

---

After that you need to [connect](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/ui) `LiveData` to a `PagedListAdapter` as shown in the following code snippet:

```
private val adapter = YourDataAdapter()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    dataList.observe(this, Observer { adapter.submitList(it) })
}
```

The sample code of adapter you can find [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/ui).

Answer (score 1):

We use Datasource when we want to do pagination using the android paging component.
there are so many ways to achieve it,

First implement paging library

```
implementation "android.arch.paging:runtime:2.1.0"
```

Now the most simple method to convert data source into LiveData> is this

```
fun getElementsLiveData(): LiveData<PagedList<Person>> {

        val data = mDao.getElements()
        return LivePagedListBuilder(data, 10).build() // 10 is page size

}
```

you can also pass configuration instead on page size

```
    fun getElementsLiveData(): LiveData<PagedList<Person>> {

     val pagedListConfig = PagedList.Config.Builder()
        .setEnablePlaceholders(true)
        .setInitialLoadSizeHint(15)
        .setPageSize(10)
        .build()

        val data = mDao.getElements()
        return LivePagedListBuilder(data, pagedListConfig).build()

}
```

Now create your pager adapter and view holder like this

```
    class ElementAdapter(
    private val clickListener: ClickListener
) : PagedListAdapter<Person, ElementViewHolder>(diffCallback) {

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ElementViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val person = getItem(position)
        with(holder) {
             // bind your data here
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ElementViewHolder =
        ElementViewHolder(parent)

    companion object {
        /**
         * This diff callback informs the PagedListAdapter how to compute list differences when new
         * PagedLists arrive.
         */
        private val diffCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Person>() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Person, newItem: Person): Boolean =
                oldItem.id == newItem.id

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: News, newItem: News): Boolean =
                oldItem.title == newItem.title
        }
    }
}
```

after that, in your activity or fragment you can simply observer the data change using viewmodel and submit your data to the adapter

```
 viewModel.getElementsLiveData().observer(this, Observer{pagedList->
  adaoter.submitList(pagedList)
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Sergey 's answer, You can use `PagedList<>.snapshot()` to get as a regular list

```
 // Get the DataSource from the database
 val dataSource: DataSource.Factory<Int, Person> = dao.getElements()

 // Get the dataSource as LiveData
 val data = dataSource.toLiveData(20 /* page size */)

 // In UI
 vm.data.observer(this, Observer{pagedList->
  // To get the pagedList as a regular list -
  val dataList = pagedList.snapshot()
 })
```

**Note**: The `snapshot()` function only gives you the currently available items in your pagedList.