# Room not retrieve data when androidx.paging.DataSource.Factory (using LiveData + Kotlin Coroutines)

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

I have a AmbassadorDAO that has a `getAll() : List<Ambassador>` that return correctly the list of Ambassadors.

**The problem becomes when I refactory my existent code** to use DataSource.Factory to paginate my list

Here is the code

### Presation Module

**Activity**

```
class AmbassadorActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...

        val viewModel by viewModel<AmbassadorViewModel>()

        val adapter = AmbassadorAdapter(this)
        list_of_ambassadors.adapter = adapter

        viewModel.ambassadors.observe(this, Observer { adapter.submitList(it) })

        viewModel.listAmbassadors()

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

**Viewmodel**

```
class AmbassadorViewModel(
    ...,
    private val getAllAmbassadorInteractor: GetAllAmbassadorInteractor
) : ViewModel() {

    ...

    // not working
    private val _ambassadors = MutableLiveData<PagedList<Ambassador>>()

    // it's working
    //private val _ambassadors = MutableLiveData<List<Ambassador>>()

    ...

    // not working
    val ambassadors : LiveData<PagedList<Ambassador>>
        get() =  _ambassadors

    // it's working
    //val ambassadors : LiveData<List<Ambassador>>
    //    get() =  _ambassadors

    ...

    fun listAmbassadors() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                ...

                // not working
                // the data not return anything
                // the livedata is notified with null
                val data = getAllAmbassadorInteractor.exec()
                _ambassadors.value = LivePagedListBuilder(data, 20).build().value

                // it's working
                //_ambassadors.value = getAllAmbassadorInteractor.exec()

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            } finally {
                ...
            }
        }
    }

}
```

### Domain Module

**Boundary between PRESENTATION (my usecase interface)**

```
interface GetAllAmbassadorInteractor {

    //suspend fun exec() : List<Ambassador>
    suspend fun exec() : DataSource.Factory<Int, Ambassador>

}
```

**Usecase implementation**

```
class GetAllAmbassadorInteractorImpl(
    private val repository: AmbassadorRepository
) : GetAllAmbassadorInteractor {

    override suspend fun exec() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { repository.getAll() }

}
```

**Boundary between DATA (my repository interface)**

```
interface AmbassadorRepository {

    ...

    //suspend fun getAll() : List<Ambassador>
    suspend fun getAll() : DataSource.Factory<Int, Ambassador>

    ...

}
```

### Data Module

**Repository implementation**

```
class AmbassadorRepositoryImpl(
    private val ambassadorDAO: AmbassadorDAO
) : AmbassadorRepository {

    ...

    override suspend fun getAll() = ambassadorDAO.getAll().map { it.toDomain() }

    ...

}
```

**My DAO**

```
@Dao
interface AmbassadorDAO {

    ...

    @Query("SELECT * FROM ${AmbassadorEntity.TABLE_NAME} ORDER BY name DESC")
    fun getAll(): DataSource.Factory<Int, AmbassadorEntity>
    //fun getAll(): List<AmbassadorEntity>

    ...

}
```

Where am I doign wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I guess your mistake is on this line in `AmbassadorViewModel` class:

```
_ambassadors.value = LivePagedListBuilder(data, 20).build().value
```

Instead of that use:

```
_ambassadors.value = LivePagedListBuilder(data, 20).build()
```

Also refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54561263/how-to-get-data-from-datasource-factory/54567410#54567410), maybe it will help.

Answer (score 1):

With the support of Kotlin extension (LifecycleScope) we can easily connect LiveData with Coroutine and you don't need to use backing properties like _ambassadors and make it MutableLiveData.

```
androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0-alpha01 or higher.
```

Like this is a function which is using Coroutine and returning a LiveData

```
/**
 * Get all news rows livedata pageList from DB using Coroutine.
 */
suspend fun getAllNewsLiveData(): LiveData<PagedList<News>> {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val data = mDao.getAllNews()
        LivePagedListBuilder(data, Constants.PAGINATION_SIZE).build()
    }

}
```

Now in UI class we can simply call this function using lifescope extension

```
  lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
        newsViewModel.getNews()?.observe(this@NewsActivity, Observer { pagedNewsList -> pagedNewsList.let { newsAdapter.submitList(pagedNewsList) } })
    }
```